# How to scan all the files or certain text and copy it to another file?

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a large application with many directories and subdirectories. Some of the files have a line with .styl file import inside. For example:

```
import './view/auth.styl';
```

I'd like to write a sh script that would scan all the files, looking for such imports and copy them to an another file (lets say 'global.styl'). Honestly, I have no idea how to write such bash scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Command

A single `grep` command should be sufficient:

```
grep -hr 'import .*\.styl' > global.styl
```

`grep` searches for lines inside files. Only lines matching a given regular expression are printed. We use the regular expression `import .*\.styl` to select all lines that contain `import` followed by something and then `.styl`.

With `-r` we search all files in the current working directory and its sub-directories recursively.

Usually lines are prefixed with filenames. `-h` disables this behavior such that only lines are printed.

`>` is a redirection and saves the output of `grep` in the file `global.styl`.

#### False Positives

Note that `import .*\.styl` is only a string search. It will match

```
import 'something/something.styl';
```

but also

```
s = "not an import a; just.a.string.with.style.";
```

You can refine the expression to be more precise, but in most cases that won't be necessary.

#### Remove Duplicates

In case the same `import` appears multiple times, for instance in different files, you might want to remove duplicates such that `global.styl` is

```
import 'a.styl';
import 'b.styl';
```

instead of

```
import 'b.styl';
import 'a.styl';
import 'a.styl';
import 'b.styl';
...
```

To this end you can use

```
grep -hr 'import .*\.styl' | sort -u > global.styl
```

#### Convert Relative Paths

If you start in the directory `dir1` and have the file `dir1/dir2/dir3/file` containing `import './path/file.styl';` you may want to convert the relative import to `import './dir2/dir3/path/file.styl';`. A quick and dirty solution is the following command (you can write it in one line):

```
grep -r 'import .*\.styl' |
sed -E 's,(.*/)*.*:(.*)(\./),\2./\1,;s,.*:,,' > global.styl
```

This solution replaces `./` with the directory of the file. Paths not containing `./` won't be processed. We assume that paths never contain `:` or some component ending with `.` (for instance `some./path`).

Comment: Thank you! What if I'd also like to change the relative paths (import './view/auth.styl'; ) to the full ones (import 'sth/sth/view.styl)?

Comment: Then the solution gets more complicated. I added a quick and dirty solution. To combine path processing with duplicate filtering apply the filtering in the last step.

Answer (score 1):

you could use find for this one:

```
find /path/to/toplevel/dir -type f -exec grep "import .*styl';" {} \; >> global.styl
```

Explanation: **find** runs from the given directory through all subdirectory. **-type f** just takes all files (not directories) and the executes a grep (finding text in those files). **{} \;** is just a placeholder for all the files found by find. The **>>** just redirects the output into the file global.styl.

or if all your files would have extension .whatever you could use

```
find /path/to/toplevel/dir -name "*.whatever" -exec grep "import .*styl';" {} \; >> global.styl
```

so instead of using all files, you just use the files with the given filename schema

if you are sure that your imports are the one and only text in the line with no spaces before and after, you could use grep "^import .*styl';$" which would check that there is nothing before (**^**) and after (**$**) that text in this line. (see [regular expressions](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_04.html) for more details on this one)

Comment: If you replace `\;` with `+` the command will be way faster. With `;` each file will start a new `grep` process. With `+` files are grouped and `grep` is called (usually) only once.